# Skip Lines by using StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a really big file with round about 30.000 Rows. I have to parse this file and can not delete entries on it. So my idea is to skip allready read lines. I tried something like this:

```
                //Gets the allready readed lines
                int readLines = GetCurrentCounter();
                //Open File
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(LogDatabasePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    string line;
                    //If File was allready read to a specified line, skip these lines
                    if (readLines != 0) reader.ReadLine().Skip(readLines);
                    //Check if new lines are available
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (counter >= readedLines)
                        {
                            //If there is text which contains the searched Testsystem-Name
                            if (line.Contains(TestSystemName.ToUpper()))
                            {
                                //Create new Database-Entry
                                new TestsystemError().GenerateNewDatabaseEntry(line, counter);
                            }
                        }
                        System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                        counter++;
                    }

                }
```

**The problem is, that the function reader.ReadLine().Skip(readLines) has no function or i use it in a wrong way.**

I need a possibility to skip lines without use the function "reader.ReadLine()" because this is very slow (i get performance problems if i have to iterate through all lines ~about 30.000 lines).

Is there a way to skip lines?  If so, would be great to share code. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you shared? How is it malfunctioning.

Comment: @Mureinik The skip-function has no impact

Comment: It's not clear when you want to skip n lines. Do you really want to read this file as often as lines are contained? Then you should better read all(`File.ReadAllLines`) and use that array.

Comment: Why is this file being opened and closed and always being re-read?

Comment: @LarsTech: The File is a really big log file where a lot of different systems are writing in. For me only a few systems are relevant. The file would be filled with new informations sometimes, so i have to re-read the whole file which costs a lot of performance to iterate through the whole document. In this case i want to skip some lines

Comment: That must be some old legacy app you have for it to rely so heavily on a log file with multiple programs accessing it for key information.  If it's important information, it shouldn't be going into a text file.  Looks like you are putting lipstick on this pig.

Answer (score 4):

The method [`reader.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadLine) returns a string.

The extension method [`Skip(readedLines)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Skip__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_) iterates that string and returns an iterator which has skipped the first `readedLines` characters in the string.

This has no effect on the reader.

If you want to skip the first *n* lines, either read the first *n* lines by calling `reader.ReadLine()` *n* times, or read the stream until you have read in *n* end-of-line character sequences before creating the reader. The latter approach avoids creating strings for the lines you want to ignore, but is more code.

If you happen to have extremely regular data so all the rows are the same length, then you can skip the stream before you create the reader

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(LogDatabasePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

stream.Seek(readedRows * lengthOfRowInBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  // etc
```

If you have the row number encoded in the row, you could also do a binary search, but that's more code.

Comment: Is there no way to get something link a binary search to start in the middle or something like that? The performance is very bad

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler yes, there are many many ways to search a file. You could to a binary search if there was something in the row to indicate the value you are searching on and the rows were in order of that value, or if the rows were all the same length you could just skip the stream by the appropriate number of bytes. But nothing in your OP indicates these conditions apply to your data.

Comment: But this means, that i can jump through the file without iterate through it right? This is the function i'm searching for

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler yes, if you data is formatted in a way that you know how much to skip by.

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler Instead of keeping track of the number of lines, keep a counter of the number of characters read by adding `line.Length + 2` (for the newline). Then `stream.Seek()` can be used to quickly skip to the last read position.

Comment: @redtetrahedron is this faster? i have to iterate in any case through the whole document?

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler it would be faster; you would not be iterating through the whole file. I posted an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of keeping track of the number of lines, keep track of the number of characters read. Then you can use `stream.Seek()` to quickly skip to the last read position instead of iterating through the whole file every time.

```
long currentPosition = GetCurrentPosition();

//Open File
FileStream stream = new FileStream(LogDatabasePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;

    // Seek to the previously read position
    stream.Seek(currentPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //Check if new lines are available
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // do stuff with the line
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        // keep track of the current character position
        currentPosition += line.Length + 2; // Add 2 for newline
    }
}

SaveCurrentPosition(currentPosition);
```

Comment: What about Stream.Position ? Or does the reader buffer and cause it to be off?

Comment: @redtetrahedron Could you explain why you are using line.length and not Stream.Position ? I've tried your example and if im using Stream.Position there is some strange behavior. The long datatype which represents the Stream.Position isn't changeing every time i think... could this be?

Comment: @PeteKirkham Yes, `StreamReader` reads in blocks, so the current stream position may not represent the position of the end of the current line.

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler Yep, what poke said... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the lines as you read them

```
//If File was allready read to a specified line, skip these lines
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && readLines < readedLines){
   readLines++
} 
if (readedLines != 0) reader.ReadLine()
//Check if new lines are available
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```